# npm ERR! Refusing to delete when Install react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, compiler-errors

I Have a Problem about NPM, I want to instal npm react-native with command **npm install -g react-native-cli** on cmd, 
But, an error suddenly appeared like this :

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Xeon\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Xeon\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.cmd: is outside C:\Users\Xeon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Xeon\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Xeon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T03_00_40_156Z-debug.log
```

I don't know why this error appears, hopefully I can find a solution here.
thank you

Comment: Please check link maybe you will get your answer [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/857)

Answer (score 0):

Check your npm/node version, make sure they install correctly

currently there's no need to install **react-native-cli** for RN 0.61

you should try

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
```

or just using expo instead

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init AwesomeProject
```

Lastly, you should read the Official Doc for more details.